# how To Enable Button On web Page with Id My Code Attached Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i am trying to enable button by giving its id as i done diabling for all button on the page how can we do for particular button with ID my code is ,

```
public static void EnableInsertBtn(Control parent)
{

    foreach (Control B in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (B.GetType() == typeof(Button))
        {
            ((Button)(B)).Enabled = false;

        }
        if (B.HasControls())
        {
            EnableInsertBtn(B);
        }

    }
```

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the button using it's ID itself.

```
btnID.Enabled = false;
```

and enable

```
btnID.Enabled = true;
```